# PHP Decimal128 string formating

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using MongoDB to store values as Decimal128 and using PHP with Twig to display them. My question is there a format the output with a thousands separator? I have tried using number_format, but that doesn't work because the value is a string not a int or float. I don't want to type cast the value because I want the value to be precision.

Examples:

```
1000.382 = 1,000.382
99.01    = 99.01
1900000  = 1,900,000
```

I wrote a function to do this. Still wondering if there is a better way to do it.

```
<?php
$n = '12345.001';

echo fNumString($n);

function fNumString ($number_string) {
    $ex_num = explode('.', $number_string);
    $whole_num_len = strlen($ex_num[0]);

    $formated = '';
    if ($whole_num_len > 3) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $whole_num_len; $i++) {
            $formated .= $ex_num[0][$i];

            if ((($whole_num_len - ($i + 1)) % 3) == 0 && $whole_num_len != ($i + 1))
                $formated .= ',';
        }
    } else
        $formated = $ex_num[0];


    if (count($ex_num) == 2)
        $formated .= '.' . $ex_num[1];

    return $formated;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output? You're referring to thousands separator but your example is 1.001. Please share a few examples of input/output (input being what you have, output what you need).

Comment: Sorry it was like that from testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- split the number string into integer and decimal parts using `explode`,
- reverse the integer part using `strrev`,
- add a thousands separator every 3 digits within that integer part using `preg_replace`,
- reverse the integer part back using `strrev`,
- return it concatenated with the decimal separator and the decimal part

Code:

```
function fNumString(string $numberString, string $decimalPoint = '.', string $thousandsSeparator = ','): string
{
  [$integerPart, $decimalPart] = array_pad(explode('.', $numberString, 2), 2, null);
  $integerPart = strrev(preg_replace('/\d{3}(?=\d)/', '\0' . $thousandsSeparator, strrev($integerPart)));

  return $integerPart . ($decimalPart ? $decimalPoint . $decimalPart : '');
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/m3jUC**

Note: you could leave out the last 2 parameters of `number_format`, I like keeping them out for clarity (and in case they change the default values later for some reason).

Comment: That doesn't work with a number like '19000000000000000000123.12399999999198'